# Notion of connected components for $\mathbb{Q}_p$-points of algebraic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, p-adic-analysis, rigid-analytic-geometry

Is there an interesting notion of connected components for the $\mathbb{Q}_p$-points of an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{Q}_p$? By "interesting" I mean a notion satisfying the following. Given a connected algebraic variety $X$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, I would like $X(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ to have finitely many connected components but not always one, similarly to what happend over $\mathbb{R}$.

An idea would be to embed $X(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ into the analytification of $X$ and take in some sense an induced topology as we do over $\mathbb{R}$. For instance one can define $X(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ to be disconnected if there is an admissible cover ${U,V}$ in $X^{an}$ whose union contains $X(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, whose intersection contains no point of $X(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and such that each $U$ and $V$ intersect $X(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ non-trivially. Could this work?

Comment: With its metric topology, $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is totally disconnected.  Are you asking about (rigid analytic) path connectedness?

Comment: A motivating example might be the following. When $G$ is a simple isotropic algebraic group, the subgroup of $G(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ generated by unipotents has finite index and is a natural candidate, to say that its cosets are the connected components. However, when $G$ is anisotropic, this subgroup is trivial, the group $G(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ is profinite and I have no idea what would be a choice of "unit connected component", except maybe the whole group.

Comment: @JasonStarr I am looking for a notion of connectedness, not path connectedness. Even though $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is totally disconnected, rigid analytic theory have a nice notion of connectedness. As I understand it, the analytification of a connected algebraic variety will be connected. I am looking for a notion that could lead different components even for connected algebraic variety. This happends when you look at $\mathbb{R}$-points of an algebraic variety with the Euclidean topology for instance.

Comment: Can you give an example of a connected $X$ such that (in your view) $X(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ should not be connected?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Brian Conrad's "Irreducible components of rigid spaces"?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly I have in mind the way it works over $\mathbb{R}$. Even for an elliptic curve $E$, $E(\mathbb{R})$ can have several connected components with the usual topology. How can this be viewed from the point of view of algebraic variety?